# The type or namespace name 'SqlWorkflowInstanceStore'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I'm building some basic workflow functionality in WF 4.0 with SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.
I have added the right references and have tried switching from client profile but still the same problem:

I get the following error in the error list in Visual Studio 2010:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'SqlWorkflowInstanceStore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm stuck and have no idea how to fix this.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Activities.DurableInstancing;
using System.Runtime.DurableInstancing;
using System.Threading;

namespace mybasicwf4
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sqlPersistenceDBConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PersistenceDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlWorkflowInstanceStore sqlWFInstanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(sqlPersistenceDBConnectionString);
            AutoResetEvent waitHandler = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new Workflow1());
            wfApp.InstanceStore = sqlWFInstanceStore;
            wfApp.Unloaded = (arg) =>
            {
                waitHandler.Set();
            };
            wfApp.PersistableIdle = (arg) =>
            {
                return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
            };
            wfApp.Run();
            waitHandler.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I got it working.

After removing the references and adding them back in the error disappeared.
I only wish I had tried this before.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error in .Net 4 when working with Workflow persistence, so thought I'll share my findings

```
The type 'System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceStore' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
```

The namespace that we are trying to use is System.Activities.DurableInstancing, BUT the assembly that we need to reference is actually System.**Runtime**.DurableInstancing

I know right:D

Hope it helps people